# How can I find the wordpress theme name from live website?

Tags: wordpress, html, wordpress-theming, css3pie

I visited a website and found that the site was developed by *Wordpress*. But I don't know how to find the **theme** name that was used to develop that site. How can I find theme **theme** name from any live site. 
I am searching this theme name of this site : https://www.fcinq.com/ 
Or is there any way to find theme html theme of this similar site?

Comment: looks like they made their own ->  you can get it here : https://themesinfo.com/theme-authors/fcinq-themes -> https://themesinfo.com/wp-template-fcinq-bin2x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fcinq.com is using custom theme `fcinq`

to find out theme name go to the site. press `ctrl + u`

you will find all source code of that site. Now `ctrl + f` and search for `wp-content/themes/`

```
wp-content/themes/*** //in place of *** you will see the theme name.
```

another way to find the theme name is press `ctrl + u` and `ctrl + f` search for `style.css`. open it, at the very beginning of that css file search for `Theme Name`

or 
search for `wp theme detector` on google.

Comment: Thank You very much. But I could,t find theme theme at **theme forest**. Is there any chances to get the thml version of this theme?

Comment: as stated it is a *custom* theme, so you will not find it anywere, since it was developed for this site

Comment: Hi, you can't find this theme on ThemeForest. It's only developed for this site. If you need an exact copy of this site you have to build it yourself.  they used  TweenMax, SVG and some other JS stuff. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Comment is completely correct on the top. At the same time; you can use "what runs" browser extension for finding wordpress themes and backend and frontend technologies which used by spesific web site. Detecting Font names, analytics and advertising tools caching mechanisms etc are other features.

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps

1. Press CTRL+U/ view source
2. find wp-content/themes/
3. right after theme you can fine theme name (eg. "wp-content/themes/YourThemeName/" )

also you can find theme name into style.css